# Node.js. Event: 'error' is not fired

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to read data from Arduino server with Node.js "net" module. Actually, all goes great, except error handling.

The problem is in "error" event. It's not fired at all. I just switched off the server and "data" event stopped, but "error" event was not fired.

Here is the simplest example.

```js
var net = require('net');

var socket = new net.Socket();
var config = {
  port: 5003,
  host: '192.168.1.66'
};

function connect() {
  socket.connect(config, function () {
    console.log('Connected to: ' + socket.remoteAddress + ':' + socket.remotePort);
  });
}

// This event is working.
socket.on('data', function () {
  console.log('Data...');
});

// This is never fired.
socket.on('error', function () {
  console.log('Error...');
});

connect();
```

Any ideas where is the problem?

Comment: Are you seeing an error? It will only be fired on error.

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino server probably closes the connection properly (without an error) when it is shut down. Listen to the 'close' event:

```
socket.on('close', function (had_error) {
  console.log('Connection closed with' + (had_error ? '' : 'out') + ' error.');
});
```

If that doesn't work try the `'timeout'` event.

Comment: Just tried `close` event and it was not fired.
`timeout` event was fired, but it's also fired when there is no data from the Arduino. I've set timeout to 3 sec and data is coming from The Arduino every 3 sec. As a result, I'm getting timeout withing data...

Comment: @DmytroDanylevskyi I am surprised to find out that the close event isn't firing. If you set the timeout to longer than the data delay (like 10 seconds) you could detect that data has stopped firing.

Comment: thanks, but I'm not sure it's a good idea. Because I don't know the delay between data refresh...